# SMS not working on Moto G, 2nd gen

Tags: sms, motorola-moto-g

I bought Moto G, 2nd Gen. Also got my old sim replaced with new micro sim. Sms on the new phone are not working. Neither I am receiving sms nor my sms are getting delivered. Calls, watsapp, internet are working fine. Please let me know if there are any settings in the mobile to enable sms

Comment: It could be down to the network/APN settings on the device, contact your network provider and ask them for the SMS APN settings.

Comment: Might be a problem with message service center number. Check once.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to SMS message center not being stored in the new SIM. Unlike other mobile devices where you can manually set the SMS message center, the latest Android update seemed to keep this setting well hidden.

You can try setting the SMS message center by opening the phone dialer and dial - `*#*#4636#*#*`. This will open the hidden setting confusingly titled as "Testing".

Under the Phone Information, you can find the setting "SMSC". Try refresh or give the correct SMS center number.

**Note**:

- I tried this and there was a refresh error / update error. The final workaround was to load the new SIM into a Samsung phone and manually set the SMS Center number. This gets stored in the SIM and then you can start using it on your Moto E / Moto G. Crazy stuff.
- I use Airtel in India

Comment: What happens is the is no setting "SMSC" in the Testing/Phone Information screen?

Comment: Faced the same issue. Re-added the number through that testing mode but didn't work. But then did the typical "restart your phone" and SMS works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

You can only receive/read messages on the message app. This is due to the Hangouts update.

You will be able to send SMS using your hangout apps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens for few Mobile networks like Airtel in India (Not sure about other countries) when you replace the older macro sim with new micro/nano sim, the sms facility will be blocked  for 1 week for security purpose (dont know what kind of security)

Comment: It doesn't seem so in my nephew's case twice. Moreover , if the sim is blocked, all network operations, including call, SMS, Internet will not work.

Comment: Only sms facility will be blocked. Happened to me when I switched to micro sim. Not sure still this security measure exist.